# Get username from page

Tags: php, facebook, curl

```
<?php
/* EDIT EMAIL AND PASSWORD */
$EMAIL = "MY EMAIL"; // here email
$PASSWORD = "MY PASS"; // here password
function cURL($url, $header=NULL, $cookie=NULL, $p=NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    if ($p) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $p);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result) {
        return $result;
    } else {
        return curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}
$a = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,null,"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$a,$b);
$c = cURL("https://login.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1",true,$b[1],"email=$EMAIL&pass=$PASSWORD");
preg_match_all('%Set-Cookie: ([^;]+);%',$c,$d);
for($i=0;$i<count($d[0]);$i++)
    $cookie.=$d[1][$i].";";
/*
NOW TO JUST OPEN ANOTHER URL EDIT THE FIRST ARGUMENT OF THE FOLLOWING FUNCTION.
TO SEND SOME DATA EDIT THE LAST ARGUMENT.
*/
echo cURL("https://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=Funny",null,$cookie,null);
?>
```

### I want to be able to get the usernames on that page.

I can access the page i want to access, i cant get the second step.

I want to get the usernames listed on that page, i don't know where to start.

Can anybody help me out with this ?

Answer (score 2):

Your method of accessing Facebook is against Facebook's Terms of Service. You should use the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/) to get this kind of data.

Comment: I readed that page 100 times and tried it out. I can not connect to Facebook and certainly not with that page whenever i try that graph.